# Does the use of an anonymous pipe introduce a memory barrier for interthread communication?

Tags: c++, windows, posix, memory-model

For example, say I allocate a struct with new and write the pointer into the write end of an anonymous pipe.

If I read the pointer from the corresponding read end, am I guaranteed to see the 'correct' contents on the struct?

Also of of interest is whether the results of socketpair() on unix & self connecting over tcp loopback on windows have the same guarantees.

The context is a server design which centralizes event dispatch with select/epoll

Comment: You should write the struct, not a pointer to it.

Comment: Are you using [Windows anonymous pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [posix ones](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)?  You've included both tags.

Comment: Anonymous pipes on Unix platforms, and tcp over loopback for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, say I allocate a struct with new and write the pointer into the write end of an anonymous pipe.
>
> If I read the pointer from the corresponding read end, am I guaranteed to see the 'correct' contents on the struct?

No. There is no guarantee that the writing CPU will have flushed the write out of its cache and made it visible to the other CPU that might do the read.

> Also of of interest is whether the results of socketpair() on unix & self connecting over tcp loopback on windows have the same guarantees.

No.

Comment: To paraphrase David earlier, which cache mechanism are you talking about, and at which point would it fail?

Comment: I'm not sure who David is. Anyway, I'm not talking a single, specific CPU or cache policy. The OP tagged their question with Windows and POSIX, which means answers should probably consider more than just a specific architecture. It could fail if one thread writes the structure to memory, then writes to the pipe, and then the other thread reads from the pipe and then reads the structure from memory. Since the structure in memory is totally separate from the data traveling through the pipe, it's possible it hasn't been synchronized across cores.

Comment: Agreed (though see my note on practical considerations). But note that doesn't answer my question, since your answer says "no guarantee that the writing CPU will have flushed the write out of its cache and made it visible to the other CPU", and what I don't understand is which cache mechanism you're referring to here and in what scenario would it cause things to fail?

Comment: comes to mind: "compiler reordering optimizations" & "CPU instruction reordering". They can break normal execution flow, But for cache... "cache coherency protocol" exists in a system (in CPU for a example).

Answer (score 2):

In practice, calling `write()`, which is a system call, will end up locking one or more data structures in the kernel, which should take care of the reordering issue. For example, POSIX requires subsequent reads to see data written before their call, which implies a lock (or some kind of acquire/release) by itself.

As for whether that's part of the formal spec of the calls, probably it's not.

Comment: 1) An implied lock is different from a memory barrier, though. Kernel locks don't have to be full memory barriers. 2) Reordering isn't the only issue; stale cache data in the CPU is also an issue.

Comment: @Cornstalks I'm just speculating here, but in the context of IO I wouldn't think RCU is what happens, but rather something at least along the lines of acquire/release. WRT the cache, see the note on POSIX. If you're talking about CPU cache itself, I think this is covered by cache coherency (bus snooping or whatever).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the CPU cache itself. If the CPU uses a [weak consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_consistency) model, then it is possible the struct's memory hasn't been synchronized across processors. Additionally, if the computer has multiple CPUs, then [things get really hard](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) (see the section of WHAT MAY NOT BE ASSUMED ABOUT MEMORY BARRIERS?)

Comment: @Cornstalks The links only talk about reordering, not cache. Also, what do you mean by "_CPU_ uses a weak consistency model"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hmm, maybe we're using the same words to talk about different things. When you say "reordering" what exactly are you talking about? When I use that word I mean the CPU executing instructions out of order (or sometimes the optimizer reordering instructions to execute them differently than originally written). When I mention CPU using a weak consistency model, I'm talking about [write-back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#WRITEPOLICIES) with a weak consistency model (as linked to earlier).

Comment: @Cornstalks We use the same definition for reordering. But AFAIK the write-back stuff should already be provided by the CPU's cache-coherency mechanisms (e.g. bus snooping). Maybe you can give a concrete example scenario of where the things you're talking about could wrong? Sorry, but I still haven't figured out what you're referring to here.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is just a memory address, so **provided you are on the same process** the pointer will be valid on the receiving thread and will point to the same struct. If you are on different processes, at best you will get immediately a memory error, at worse you will read (or write) to a random memory which is essentially Undefined Behaviour.

Will you read the correct content? Neither better nor worse than if your pointer was in a static variable shared by both threads: you still have to do some *synchronization* if you want consistency.

Will the kind of transfer address matter between static memory (shared by threads), anonymous pipes, socket pairs, tcp loopback, etc.? No: all those channels transfers *bytes*, so if you pass a memory address, you will get your memory address. What is left you then is synchronization, because here you are just sharing a memory address.

If you do not use any other synchronization, anything can happen (did I already spoke of Undefined Behaviour?):

- reading thread can access memory before it has been written by writing one giving stale data
- if you forgot to declare the struct members as volatile, reading thread can keep using cached values, here again getting stale data
- reading thread can read partially written data meaning incoherent data

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question with, so far, only one correct answer from Cornstalks.

Within the same (multi-threaded) process there are no guarantees since pointer and data follow different paths to reach their destination.
Implicit acquire/release guarantees do not apply since the struct data cannot piggyback on the pointer through the cache and formally you are dealing with a data race.

However, looking at how the pointer and the struct data itself reach the second thread (through the pipe and memory cache respectively), there is a real chance that this mechanism is not going to cause any harm.
Sending the pointer to a peer thread takes 3 system calls (`write()` in the sending thread, `select()` and `read()` in the receiving thread) which is (relatively) expensive and by the time the pointer value is available
in the receiving thread, the struct data probably has arrived long before.

Note that this is just an observation, the mechanism is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your case might be reduced to this 2 threads model:

```
int data = 0;
std::atomic<int*> atomicPtr{nullptr};
//...

void thread1()
{
    data = 42;
    atomicPtr.store(&integer, std::memory_order_release);
}

void thread2()
{
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    while(!ptr)
        ptr = atomicPtr.load(std::memory_order_consume);
    assert(*ptr == 42);
}
```

Since you have 2 processes you can't use one atomic variable across them but since you listed [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) you can omit `atomicPtr.load(std::memory_order_consume)` from the consuming part because, AFAIK, all the architectures Windows is running on guarantee this load to be correct without any barrier on the loading side. In fact, I think there are not much architectures out there where that instruction would not be a NO-OP(I heard only about DEC Alpha)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Serge Ballesta's answer. Within the same process, it's feasible to send and receive object address via anonymous pipe.

Since the `write` system call is guaranteed to be atomic when message size is below `PIPE_BUF` (normally 4096 bytes), so multi-producer threads will not mess up each other's object address (8 bytes for 64 bit applications).

Talk is cheap, here is the demo code for Linux (defensive code and error handlers are omitted for simplicity). Just copy & paste to `pipe_ipc_demo.cc` then compile & run the test.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>

template<class T> class MPSCQ { // pipe based Multi Producer Single Consumer Queue
public:
        MPSCQ();
        ~MPSCQ();
        int producerPush(const T* t); 
        T* consumerPoll(double timeout = 1.0);
private:
        void _consumeFd();
        int _selectFdConsumer(double timeout);
        T* _popFront();
private:
        int _fdProducer;
        int _fdConsumer;
        char* _consumerBuf;
        std::string* _partial;
        std::list<T*>* _list;
        static const int _PTR_SIZE;
        static const int _CONSUMER_BUF_SIZE;
};

template<class T> const int MPSCQ<T>::_PTR_SIZE = sizeof(void*);
template<class T> const int MPSCQ<T>::_CONSUMER_BUF_SIZE = 1024;

template<class T> MPSCQ<T>::MPSCQ() :
        _fdProducer(-1),
        _fdConsumer(-1) {
        _consumerBuf = new char[_CONSUMER_BUF_SIZE];
        _partial = new std::string;     // for holding partial pointer address
        _list = new std::list<T*>;      // unconsumed T* cache
        int fd_[2];
        int r = pipe(fd_);
        _fdConsumer = fd_[0];
        _fdProducer = fd_[1];
}


template<class T> MPSCQ<T>::~MPSCQ() { /* omitted */ }

template<class T> int MPSCQ<T>::producerPush(const T* t) {
        return t == NULL ? 0 : write(_fdProducer, &t, _PTR_SIZE);
}

template<class T> T* MPSCQ<T>::consumerPoll(double timeout) {
        T* t = _popFront();
        if (t != NULL) {
                return t;
        }
        if (_selectFdConsumer(timeout) <= 0) {  // timeout or error
                return NULL;
        }
        _consumeFd();
        return _popFront();
}

template<class T> void MPSCQ<T>::_consumeFd() {
        memcpy(_consumerBuf, _partial->data(), _partial->length());
        ssize_t r = read(_fdConsumer, _consumerBuf, _CONSUMER_BUF_SIZE - _partial->length());
        if (r <= 0) {   // EOF or error, error handler omitted
                return;
        }
        const char* p = _consumerBuf;
        int remaining_len_ = _partial->length() + r;
        T* t;
        while (remaining_len_ >= _PTR_SIZE) {
                memcpy(&t, p, _PTR_SIZE);
                _list->push_back(t);
                remaining_len_ -= _PTR_SIZE;
                p += _PTR_SIZE;
        }
        *_partial = std::string(p, remaining_len_);
}

template<class T> int MPSCQ<T>::_selectFdConsumer(double timeout) {
        int r;
        int nfds_ = _fdConsumer + 1;
        fd_set readfds_;
        struct timeval timeout_;
        int64_t usec_ = timeout * 1000000.0;
        while (true) {
                timeout_.tv_sec = usec_ / 1000000;
                timeout_.tv_usec = usec_ % 1000000;
                FD_ZERO(&readfds_);
                FD_SET(_fdConsumer, &readfds_);
                r = select(nfds_, &readfds_, NULL, NULL, &timeout_);
                if (r < 0 && errno == EINTR) {
                        continue;
                }
                return r;
        }
}

template<class T> T* MPSCQ<T>::_popFront() {
        if (!_list->empty()) {
                T* t = _list->front();
                _list->pop_front();
                return t;
        } else {
                return NULL;
        }
}

// = = = = = test code below = = = = =

#define _LOOP_CNT    5000000
#define _ONE_MILLION 1000000
#define _PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM 2

struct TestMsg {        // all public
        int _threadId;
        int _msgId;
        int64_t _val;
        TestMsg(int thread_id, int msg_id, int64_t val) :
                _threadId(thread_id),
                _msgId(msg_id),
                _val(val) { };
};

static MPSCQ<TestMsg> _QUEUE;
static int64_t _SUM = 0;

void* functor_producer(void* arg) {
        int my_thr_id_ = pthread_self();
        TestMsg* msg_;
        for (int i = 0; i <= _LOOP_CNT; ++ i) {
                if (i == _LOOP_CNT) {
                        msg_ = new TestMsg(my_thr_id_, i, -1);
                } else {
                        msg_ = new TestMsg(my_thr_id_, i, i + 1);
                }
                _QUEUE.producerPush(msg_);
        }
        return NULL;
}


void* functor_consumer(void* arg) {
        int msg_cnt_ = 0;
        int stop_cnt_ = 0;
        TestMsg* msg_;
        while (true) {
                if ((msg_ = _QUEUE.consumerPoll()) == NULL) {
                        continue;
                }
                int64_t val_ = msg_->_val;
                delete msg_;
                if (val_ <= 0) {
                        if ((++ stop_cnt_) >= _PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM) {
                                printf("All done, _SUM=%ld\n", _SUM);
                                break;
                        }
                } else {
                        _SUM += val_;
                        if ((++ msg_cnt_) % _ONE_MILLION == 0) {
                                printf("msg_cnt_=%d, _SUM=%ld\n", msg_cnt_, _SUM);
                        }
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* const* argv) {
        pthread_t consumer_;
        pthread_create(&consumer_, NULL, functor_consumer, NULL);
        pthread_t producers_[_PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM];
        for (int i = 0; i < _PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM; ++ i) {
                pthread_create(&producers_[i], NULL, functor_producer, NULL);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _PRODUCER_THREAD_NUM; ++ i) {
                pthread_join(producers_[i], NULL);
        }
        pthread_join(consumer_, NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

And here is test result ( `2 * sum(1..5000000) == (1 + 5000000) * 5000000 == 25000005000000` ):

```
$ g++ -o pipe_ipc_demo pipe_ipc_demo.cc -lpthread
$ ./pipe_ipc_demo    ## output may vary except for the final _SUM
msg_cnt_=1000000, _SUM=251244261289
msg_cnt_=2000000, _SUM=1000708879236
msg_cnt_=3000000, _SUM=2250159002500
msg_cnt_=4000000, _SUM=4000785160225
msg_cnt_=5000000, _SUM=6251640644676
msg_cnt_=6000000, _SUM=9003167062500
msg_cnt_=7000000, _SUM=12252615629881
msg_cnt_=8000000, _SUM=16002380952516
msg_cnt_=9000000, _SUM=20252025092401
msg_cnt_=10000000, _SUM=25000005000000
All done, _SUM=25000005000000
```

The technique showed here is used in our production applications. One typical usage is the consumer thread acts as a log writer, and worker threads can write log messages almost asynchronously. Yes, ***almost*** means sometimes writer threads may be blocked in `write()` when pipe is full, and this is a reliable congestion control feature provided by OS.